# Changing the size of a pixel depending on it's color with GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a application that will encode data for bearing and intensity using 32 bits.  My fragment shader already decodes the values and then sets the color depending on bearing and intensity.

I'm wondering if it's also possible, via shader, to change the size (and possibly shape) of the drawn pixel.

As an example, let's say we have 4 possible values for intensity, then 0 would cause a single pixel to be drawn, 1 would draw a 2x2 square, 2 a 4x4 square and 3 a circle with a radius of 6 pixels.

In the past, we had to do all this on the CPU side and I was hoping to offload this job to the GPU.

Comment: Good luck drawing a circle using a fragment shader. If you use actual primitives for all of this instead you would probably get better results. You can sample textures from vertex or geometry shaders (without certain types of filtering) the same as fragment. I do not know if is practical to elaborate on this solution because I do not know the size of or frequency that your data set changes.

Comment: My worst case is an array of 500x750 that gets refreshed twice per second.

Answer (score 0):

No, fragment shaders cannot affect the "size" of the data they write. Once something has been rasterized into [fragments](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment), it doesn't really have a "size" anymore.

If you're rendering [`GL_POINTS` primitives](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Point_Primitive), you can change their size from the vertex shader. As for point sizes, it's rather difficult to ensure that a particular point covers an exact number of fragments.

Comment: My application "draws" data onto a texture. This data is then decoded by a fragment shader. Could a vertex shader be used to do what I need? It doesn't need to be done by my fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came into my mind is doing something similiar to blur technique, but instead of bluring the texture, we use it to look for neighbouring texels with a range to check if it has the intensity above 1.0f. if yes, then set the current texel color to for example red.

If you're using a fbo that is 1:1 in comparison to window size, use 1/width and 1/height in texture coordinates to get approximately 1 pixel (well not exactly because it is not a pixel but texel, just nearly)

Although this work just fine, the downside of this is it is very expensive as it will have n^2 complexity and probably some branching.

Edit: after thinking awhile this might not work for size with even number